# How to get template name from pdf

Tags: pdf, templates

Is it possible to get information about the LaTex template used from a pdf? I tried `pdfinfo`, but it only showed me the pdfTeX version. I need to know the template name and any additional packages used.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What exactly do you mean by 'template', do you mean the documentclass? In any case, this information is usually not stored in the pdf, so you need to do some detective work like finding the author instructions on the web page for a journal or conference or university thesis (if the document is any of these), or ask the author directly (for example by e-mail). If you have a link then you can post it here, there might be somebody who knows what it is - note however that such a request is off-topic and your question might be closed because of that, but still you may get

Comment: some useful leads in the comments.

Comment: yes, with template I mean documentclass.